# Reduce spacing between items - multi select dropdown

Tags: css, angular

I am using https://github.com/softsimon/angular-2-dropdown-multiselect to create a multi select dropdown in angular 4.

I would like to change the padding on items that appear in the dropdown. From developer tools, it seems padding is set to 3px and 20px

```
.dropdown-menu>li>a {
    display: block;
    padding: 3px 20px;
    clear: both;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #333;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Is there a way that I can apply a custom CSS on items to get rid of the padding. If I override 'dropdown-menu>li>a' in my CSS, then it could impact other elements as well

```
.dropdown-menu>li>a {
    display: block;
    padding: 1px 5px;
    clear: both;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #333;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

[image: Elements with spacing]

the area highlighted in black is the whitepsace that I would like to get rid of.

Comment: I don't really get what the problem is... Give your base element a custom class (or id) and apply style from there..

Comment: I dont' see any problem with other elements when changing the padding. Can you clarify what element's padding you want to change? Also what dropdown style you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to override the style but make sure that you wrap it inside another class so that it would be applied only within that class.

For example:
HTML:

```
<div class="customDropdown">
 //Use drop down here
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    .customDropdown .dropdown-menu>li>a {
        display: block;
        padding: 1px 5px;
        clear: both;
        font-weight: 400;
        line-height: 1.42857143;
        color: #333;
        white-space: nowrap;
     }
```

Comment: Yeah, I missed the syntax. Edited the answer now. The earlier one was using Sass syntax.